# SharePoint 2013 Query dynamic text and connect to filiter values

Tags: 2013, query, data, visio, visio-services

I have an embedded Visio Diagram that has different filter values for each shape. I have the filter values that are connected to List and Library's, and when a user selects a particular shape it will query the correct filter data in the list and Library.  I will like to now use the filter to display text only when a user selects a Visio shape.

I appreciate any suggestions and guidance.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!